# Can't get the values for radio buttons

Tags: php, forms

I'm building a form to post data to a MySQL database, I have it all finished but whenever I test it, the values for radio buttons in just one part all come out as 0 in the data base.
So this for example shows up with the proper values for whatever is filled out in the form.

```
<div class="indented">
            Stronger?
            <input type="radio" name="q4a" value="1" id="q4aY" />
            <label for="q4aY"><span></span>Yes/ </label>
            <input type="radio" name="q4a" value="0" id="q4aN" />
            <label for="q4aN"><span></span>No</label><br />
            More likely to succeed?
            <input type="radio" name="q4b" value="1" id="q4bY" />
            <label for="q4bY"><span></span>Yes/ </label>
            <input type="radio" name="q4b" value="0" id="q4bN" />
            <label for="q4bN"><span></span>No</label><br />
            More known/visible/recognized?
            <input type="radio" name="q4c" value="1" id="q4cY" />
            <label for="q4cY"><span></span>Yes/ </label>
            <input type="radio" name="q4c" value="0" id="q4cN" />
            <label for="q4cN"><span></span>No</label><br />
            <br />
</div>
```

But this, comes back as zero every time it's filled out no matter what.

```
<table id="section2Table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="colgroup" colspan="4">Before ELP</th>
                    <th scope="col">Activities that support Entrepreneurship</th>
                    <th scope="colgroup" colspan="4">Now</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Yearly</th>
                    <th>Quarterly</th>
                    <th>Monthly</th>
                    <th>Weekly</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Yearly</th>
                    <th>Quarterly</th>
                    <th>Monthly</th>
                    <th>Weekly</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1b" value="1" id="1yearlyb" />
                    <label for="1yearlyb"><div align="center"></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1b" value="4" id="1quarterlyb" />
                    <label for="1quarterlyb"><div align="center"></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1b" value="12" id="1montlyb" />
                    <label for="1montlyb"><div align="center"></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1b" value="52" id="1weeklyb" />
                    <label for="1weeklyb"><div align="center"></div></label></td>
                    <td class="q7question">Strategically lead others as a member of an advisory board or board of directors (company or NGO, including JA, chamber)</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1n" value="1" id="1yearlyn" />
                    <label for="1yearlyn"><div align="center"><span id="check"></span></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1n" value="4" id="1quarterlyn" />
                    <label for="1quarterlyn"><div align="center"><span id="check"></span></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1n" value="12" id="1montlyn" />
                    <label for="1montlyn"><div align="center"><span id="check"></span></div></label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="7_1n" value="52" id="1weeklyn" />
                    <label for="1weeklyn"><div align="center"><span id="check"></span></div></label></td>
                </tr>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, the PHP code on the posting page is all the same, I'll post it if you want to take a look but all the variables are identified that same way. I'd love some help on this as I'm pretty new to this stuff.
Thanks!

Comment: the post it please :)

Comment: Please post the relevant PHP that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Run your HTML through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). You will find quite some errors. One of which is (there are more than one of those):

```
value of attribute "ID" invalid: "1" cannot start a name 
    <input type="radio" id="1yearlyb" value="1" name="7_1b">
                            ^
```

> **125: value of attribute Y invalid: X cannot start a name**
>
> It is possible that you violated the naming convention for this attribute. For example, id and name attributes must begin with a
>   letter, not a digit.

Also there appear to be `div`'s inside `label`s which is pointed out as invalid too. I suggest you fix the syntax errors in your HTML and try again from there.

I do not know if this will fix your issues but it is never a bad idea to be standard conform.

Here is a nice [sandbox environment](http://phpfiddle.org/) where you can try around, setup the problematic situation and have us debug it.

Comment: +1 this.  It is easier to pinpoint the actual cause of a problem if other mistakes are rooted out.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value is not the current state of the button.

Instead it's the value of the radiobutton if it is selected.

Example: If the radiobutton is selected, and if the defined value is YES, then in php you'll recieve YES, but if it's not selected, you wont recieve anything.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding - You are saying the radio button should be selected.  The OP is saying the radio button is selected - "every time it's filled out"